# ProcessInfo Linux/Windows incompatibility

Tags: linux, .net-core, processstartinfo

I'm trying to run same process as a child of current process. Showed below code works just fine under windows, but fails in Linux with error

No executable found matching command "dotnet-MyDll.dll"

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "dotnet",
            Arguments = "MyDll.dll " + id.ToString()
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Starting child process...");
        var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
        return process;
```

Ive also tried
FileName = "dotnet MyDll.dll"+ id.ToString(),
but it ends up with different error
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No such file or directory

I've also tried

```
    var parentP = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    string fullPath = parentP.MainModule.FileName;
    var command = fullPath+" "+Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location+" "+ id.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("Command = "+command);
    var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = command
    };
    var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
```

Still
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No such file or directory

I've also tried:

```
var parrentP = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    string fullPath = parrentP.MainModule.FileName;
    var command = "\"" + fullPath + "\" " ;
    var args = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + " " + id;
    var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = command,
        Arguments = args
    };
        var process = Process.Start(processInfo);

Exception No such file or directory
Exception at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
```

**what is proper way of running currently running dll again under Linux with dotnet core**